# ng new hello-world not working and npm cache clean not working too

Tags: angular, npm, angular5, angular6

i get this error when trying to generate a new app and tried ng cache clean --force but it doesn't work
tried to reinstall node.js and npm and angular cli but none of those worked for me 
i know this may seems like it is duplicated but it is not i'm having this even when i write npm cache clean --force

```
C:\Users\ahmed\Desktop>npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.

C:\Users\ahmed\Desktop>ng new hello-world
CREATE hello-world/angular.json (3593 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/package.json (1315 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/README.md (1027 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/tsconfig.json (384 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/tslint.json (2805 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/.editorconfig (245 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/.gitignore (503 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/environments/environment.ts (631 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/favicon.ico (5430 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/index.html (297 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/main.ts (370 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/polyfills.ts (3194 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/test.ts (642 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/browserslist (375 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/karma.conf.js (964 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/tsconfig.app.json (194 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/tsconfig.spec.json (282 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/tslint.json (314 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/app/app.module.ts (314 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/app/app.component.html (1141 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (994 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/app/app.component.ts (207 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/e2e/protractor.conf.js (752 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (307 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/e2e/src/app.po.ts (208 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json (213 bytes)
npm WARN deprecated istanbul-lib-hook@1.2.1: 1.2.0 should have been a major 
version bump
[ .................] - fetchMetadata: sill pacote version manifest for 
parseuri@0.0.5 fetched in 404ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this.

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```

Comment: npm ERR! path C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\angular-cli-15394168\upgrade\version.js
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\angular-cli-15394168\upgrade\version.js'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\angular-cli-15394168\upgrade\version.js'
npm ERR!   cause:

Comment: npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\angular-cli-15394168\upgrade\version.js'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!      path: 'C:\\Users\\ahmed\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\.staging\\angular-cli-15394168\\upgrade\\version.js' },
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:\\Users\\ahmed\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\.staging\\angular-cli-15394168\\upgrade\\version.js\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,

Comment: npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\ahmed\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\.staging\\angular-cli-15394168\\upgrade\\version.js' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running

Comment: npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

try this (according to https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit)

```
npm audit fix
```

it will Scan your project for vulnerabilities and automatically install any compatible updates to vulnerable dependencies